# Checking file extensions on multiple files

Tags: c#, file-upload

I am trying to combine 5 filenames into one string to check the extensions of the files which have been uploaded via users and allow only .jpg , .png, and .jpeg but I am not sure my way is correct especially the part of:

```
string filess = "FileExtentio, FileExtentio2, FileExtentio3, FileExtentio4, FileExtentio5";
```

So could you give me your advice of the correct way to do this part of the code

```
if (FileUploadImg1.HasFile || FileUploadImg2.HasFile || FileUploadImg3.HasFile || FileUploadImg4.HasFile || FileUploadImg5.HasFile)
                {
                    string FileExtentio = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg1.FileName);
                    string FileExtentio2 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg2.FileName);
                    string FileExtentio3 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg3.FileName);
                    string FileExtentio4 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg4.FileName);
                    string FileExtentio5 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg5.FileName);

                    string filess = "FileExtentio, FileExtentio2, FileExtentio3, FileExtentio4, FileExtentio5";

                    if (filess.ToLower() == ".jpeg" && filess.ToLower() == ".png" && filess.ToLower() == ".jpeg")
                    {
```

Comment: So... is the string `filess` a list of extensions separated by commas or...

Comment: I simply guess what you are looking for is string concatenation? E.g. `filess = FileExtentio + ", " + FileExtentio2 + ", " + ...` or `filess = string.Format("{0}, {1}, ...", FileExtentio, FileExtentio2, ...)` or `filess = $"{FileExtentio}, {FileExtentio2}, ..."`

Comment: @Isaiah Taylor yes its separated by commas the original one is:  var filess = new[] { FileExtentio, FileExtentio2, FileExtentio3, FileExtentio4, FileExtentio5 }; but thats is not working with the second line as var cant accept .ToLower so i tried a lot to fix so i decide to convert from var to string then i can get ToLower but i am not sure my way is correct so if you have a correct way to check the files extension and allow only the three images formats then i will be thankful

Comment: @Manuel Zelenka yeah what you mean is correct plus i am looking for a help in case if there is better way to check files extensions and allow only three image format before process the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `List<string>` which is very useful.

```
List<string> fileExtentions = new List<string>();

if (FileUploadImg1.HasFile)
   fileExtentions.Add(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg1.FileName));

if (FileUploadImg2.HasFile)
   fileExtentions.Add(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg2.FileName));

if (FileUploadImg3.HasFile)
   fileExtentions.Add(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg3.FileName));

if (FileUploadImg4.HasFile)
   fileExtentions.Add(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg4.FileName));

if (FileUploadImg5.HasFile)
   fileExtentions.Add(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg5.FileName));

if(fileExtentions.Any(f=>!f.Equals(".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                         !f.Equals(".jpeg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                         !f.Equals(".png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
   //Invalid file format detected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above your code block of `string FileExtensio` stuff, add this:

```
string isValid = 'true';
```

Then, for each of those lines that are like

```
string FileExtentio = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg1.FileName);
```

change to

```
string FileExtentioTemp = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg1.FileName);
string FileExtentio = FileExtentioTemp == 'jpg' || FileExtenioTemp == 'png' || FileExtentioTemp == 'jpeg' ? FileExtentio : isValid = false;
```

Then, for your condition, just say

```
if(isValid == 'true'){
    doStuff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really hope that the following first line is possible in asp. This solution would give you the opportunity to act for each file differently and looks in my opinion a little bit cleaner.

```
var fileUploads = new List<FileUpload>
                      {
                          FileUploadImg1,
                          FileUploadImg2,
                          FileUploadImg3,
                          FileUploadImg4,
                          FileUploadImg5,
                      };

var allowedExtensions = new List<string>{ ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" };

foreach(FileUpload fileUpload in fileUploads)
{
    if(!fileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        continue;
    }  

    if(allowedExtensions.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileUpload.FileName)))
    {
        // do stuff with valid file
    }
    else
    {
        // do stuff with invalid file
    }
}
```